# How to convert Pandas Dataframe to type String in Spark

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am working on Databricks. I have loaded a CSV file into a Spark Dataframe as type String by default. I then converted the Spark Dataframe into a Pandas DataFrame with the `.toPandas` command.

The issue I am having is the `.toPandas` is converting this entire Dataframe into type Object by default. I have tried to convert the entire Dataframe back into type String by the

```
df[x] = df[x].astype(str)
```

but that did not work.

Is there any other way that I can do this?

Comment: In `pandas` data frame, the data type of string column is shown as *object*, so it's possible that your column is already string type. You can further check this by looking at `df[x].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str)).all()`.

Comment: @Psidom I am assuming that if what you provided outputs as True, then all the columns are indeed of type String? Also, when I am running this command: "df[lst[col]] = pd.to_numeric(df[lst[col]], errors='coerce', downcast='float')" I am getting this error: "to_numeric() got an unexpected keyword argument 'downcast" which led me to believe that it did not convert properly as this worked before I put this into Spark.